# Validation input handled by nested directive

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

Basically I want to display validation message of an ngModel at a parent directive, but the input is handled inside a nested directive.

So far the validation is not propagated and the only way I can find so far is to $watch the $valid and $error variable from the nested directive and find a way to propagate it to the parent.

I have come across `require: "^ngModel"` but per my last try, it doesn't propage the validation to parent scope.

Wonder if there is a way to do so, beside the hack trying to watch the $error and propage it up?

**Edit**:
Here is a codepen demonstrate my issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJygp

In the code pen, I have 2 directive: parent-directive and child-directive. The validation is handled inside the child-directive but I want to display the validation message at the parent-directive.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve. A fiddle (or some sample code) would help...

Comment: Thanks for asking. I updated my question with a codepen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of stuff, the **[`form`/`ngForm` directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)** is really useful.
It instantiates a **[FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)** and gives you access to every input or select child element (with an `ngModel` and a name). I strongly advice taking a close look at the relevant documentation (linked above).

Among others, you can access the validity status of any child element (referecingit by its name), like this:

```
<!-- Creates a `parentForm` property in the current scope -->
<!-- that will give access to child control-elements      -->
<div ng-form name="parentForm">
    <!-- Creates a child control-element, whose properties  -->
    <!-- will be accessible under `parentForm.childControl` -->
    <input type="text" name="childControl" ng-model="someModel" />

    <!-- Uses the various properties of the child control-element          -->
    <!-- available to the parent from-element (through the FormController) -->
    <div>
        Child control-element info:<br />
        pristine: {{parentForm.childControl.$pristine}}<br />
        dirty:    {{parentForm.childControl.$dirty}}   <br />
        valid:    {{parentForm.childControl.$valid}}   <br />
        invalid:  {{parentForm.childControl.$invalid}} <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/odCvt/?editors=101)** based on your original codepen.

Comment: Thanks. Just looked at ngForm a couple of days ago and it provides a way to solve my problem. By the way, looking at your codepen, I don't see you are assigning an ngModel nor name to the input inside child-directive but validation can still happen. What kind of sorcery is that?

Comment: Because I use 'replace: true' the `<input>` element will replace the original markup (`<child-directive name="childControl" ng-model="ngModel"></child-directive>`) and will also "inherit" all its attributes (including `ng-model` and `name`).

Comment: BTW, feel free to accept the answer if it solves the problem.